# Проигрывание аудио файла из папки assets

Tags: java, android

Аудио файл "vv.mp3" находится в папке assets. При нажатии на кнопку Play файл проигрывается, если нажать на кнопку Pause или Stop проигрывание файла соответственно временно прекращается или заканчивается. **Но!** Если опять нажать на кнопку Play приложение **почему-то крошится**. Подскажите, что не так? Спасибо.

***layout/activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:text="Play"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="button1PlayClick"
                android:id="@+id/button1Play"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Pause"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="button2PauseClick"
                android:id="@+id/button2Pause"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Stop"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="button3StopClick"
                android:id="@+id/button3Stop"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***ru/site/a1/MainActivity.java***

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private Button button1Play = null;
 private Button button2Pause = null;
 private Button button3Stop = null;

 private MediaPlayer player = null;
 private AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //ориентация портретная
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

  button1Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1Play);
  button2Pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2Pause);
  button3Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3Stop);
  player = new MediaPlayer();

  button1Play.setEnabled(true);
  button2Pause.setEnabled(false);
  button3Stop.setEnabled(false);

  //обработчик корректного завершения
  player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    player.stop();
    try {
     player.prepare();
     player.seekTo(0);
    }
    catch (Throwable exc) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplication(), exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
  });

 }

 //Play
 public void button1PlayClick(View view) {
  //источник аудио — в папке assets
  player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

  try {
   descriptor = getAssets().openFd("vv.mp3");
   player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
   descriptor.close();
   player.prepare();

   if(!player.isPlaying()) {
    player.start();

    button1Play.setEnabled(false);
    button2Pause.setEnabled(true);
    button3Stop.setEnabled(true);
   }
  }
  catch (IOException exc) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 //Pause
 public void button2PauseClick(View view) {
  if(player.isPlaying()) {
   player.pause();

   button1Play.setEnabled(true);
   button2Pause.setEnabled(false);
   button3Stop.setEnabled(true);
  }
 }

 //Stop
 public void button3StopClick(View view) {
  player.stop();
  try {
   player.prepare();
   player.seekTo(0);
  }
  catch (Throwable exc) {
   Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  button1Play.setEnabled(true);
  button2Pause.setEnabled(false);
  button3Stop.setEnabled(false);
 }

 //переопределяем метод для освобождения ресурса плеера и его остановки
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  player.stop();
  if(player.isPlaying()) {
   try {
    player.prepare();
    player.seekTo(0);
   }
   catch (Throwable exc) {
    Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Саму ошибку добавь.

Comment: `setDataSource` можно вызывать только в состоянии idle - то есть плейер создан, но не инициализирован, либо сброшен вызовом `reset()`